# regex for capturing time not getting two digits before colon, only one

Tags: regex, r, grepl

my regex seems like it should work but is returning unexpected results.

I'm using R. If you don't use those don't worry I think this is pretty similar to some other flavors of regex. and The R documentation says that {n,m} syntax should work: "{n,m}
The preceding item is matched at least n times, but not more than m times."

```
re <- ".*\\s*(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*[APM]{2})\\s*\\s*([Aa]lbuterol|[Pp]rednison).*(per order[s]*)\\s*.*"
```

I want to capture the time (e.g. 10:47 AM, 3:04 AM) a drug was given from some free text notes.

I'm getting 3:04 AM just fine, but for 10:47 AM I'm getting 0:47 AM instead.  I've tried quite a few different things now and for some reason can't get that first digit to come over. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide some examples together with the expected output.

Comment: I would `[AP]M` rather than `[APM]{2}` to avoid false matches (AA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you make the first `\\s*` non-greedy, i.e., `\\s*?`.

```
vec <- c("some text 10:47 AM text", "another text 3:04 AM text")
sub(".*\\s*?(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}\\s*[APM]{2})\\s*.*", "\\1", vec)
# [1] "10:47 AM" "3:04 AM"
```

Answer (score 4):

the `.*` at the beginning is greedy, so `.*\\s*` matches everything up to and including the first digit of the time (the longest it can take and still find a match). Use `[^\\d]*\\s*` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach using `rm_time` from a package I maintain **qdapRegex** (>= v. 0.2.0):

```
x <- "I'm getting 3:04 AM just fine, but for 10:47 AM I'm getting 0:47 AM instead."

library(qdapRegex)
rm_default(x, extract=TRUE, pat = "@rm_time2")
[1] "3:04 AM"  "10:47 AM" "0:47 AM"
```

If you want to see the regex behind the scene use the `grab` function with the function name:

```
grab("@rm_time2")
## [1] "(\\d{0,2}:\\d{2}(?:[:.]\\d+)?)(\\s+(([AP]\\.{0,1}M\\.{0,1})|([ap]\\.{0,1}m\\.{0,1})))"
```

And the picto-explanation compliments of https://www.debuggex.com:

[image]